# Powershell to get group, members and member of details

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use powershell to get a list of global groups in an OU and output the global group name, the members and the domain local groups the global group is a member of, so far I have the output below, but how do I get the output for the "member of" details

```
$OU = 'OU=Role Groups,OU=USG,OU=Groups,OU=xxx,OU=xxxxxx,DC=xxxxxxx,DC=xxx'

$Groups =  Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $OU
$Data = foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Recursive | Select-Object @{Name='Group';Expression={$Group.Name}}, @{Name='Member';Expression={$_.Name}}
}
$Data | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\FolderPermissions.csv"
```

Comment: member of details for the users or groups?

Comment: Use tools that will right the baseline code for you, that you can then use as-is or tweak as needed. [windows 'Active Directory Administrative Center' 'PowerShell History Viewer'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=windows%20%27Active%20Directory%20Administrative%20Center%27%20%27PowerShell%20History%20Viewer%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=windows%20%27active%20directory%20administrative%20center%27%20%27powershell%20h%27&sc=0-63&sk=&cvid=6A829C7678744459BBC33E999FDDC630)

Comment: Your use case is a very common thing, with lots of examples all over the web. So, no reason to do this from scratch, or struggle with it. [PowerShell 'get group, members and member of details'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=PowerShell+%27get+group%2C+members+and+member+of+details%27&t=h_&ia=web).

Answer (score 0):

Why not take a more direct approach as defined in the help files?

> [Get-ADGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroup?view=windowsserver2019-ps)
>
> [Get-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adgroupmember?view=winserver2012-ps#:%7E:text=Get-ADGroup%20Member%201%20Description.%20The%20Get-ADGroupMember%20cmdlet%20gets,Parameters.%20Specifies%20the%20authentication%20method%20to%20use.%20)

```
Get-ADGroup | 
Where-Object {GroupScope -eq 'Global'} | 
Get-ADGroupMember
```

Or

```
$OU = 'OU=Role Groups,OU=USG,OU=Groups,OU=xxx,OU=xxxxxx,DC=xxxxxxx,DC=xxx'
Get-ADGroup -Filter "GroupScope -eq 'Global'" -SearchBase $OU | 
Get-ADGroupMember | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName
```